# Call to a member function cadastrarDados() on null - Laravel

Tags: php, mvc, construtor, laravel-5.6

Bom dia a todos,

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Laravel 5.6 utilizando o PHP 7.2, estou com problemas ao utilizar o DI(dependency injection) no construtor, visto que ao criar o objeto manualmente o algoritmo funciona perfeitamente, segue exemplo:

Este NÃO Funciona:

CentralController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Central;

class CentralController extends BaseController
{

  protected $central;
  public function __construct(Central $central)
  {
    $this->central = $central;
  }

 public function centralParser(Request $request)
 {
 $this->central->cadastrarDados($request->all());
  ...
 }
```

BaseController

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use App\Models\Usuario;

 class BaseController extends ResponseController
 {
  protected $usuario;
  public function __construct(Usuario $usuario)
  {
    $this->usuario = $usuario;
  }

  //metodos......
 }
```

---

Este Funciona:

CentralController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Central;

class CentralController extends BaseController
{

     public function centralParser(Request $request)
     {
     $central = new Central();
     $central->cadastrarDados($request->all());
      ...
     }
 }
```

BaseController

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use App\Models\Usuario;

 class BaseController extends ResponseController
 {
  protected $usuario;
  public function __construct(Usuario $usuario)
  {
    $this->usuario = $usuario;
  }

  //metodos......
 }
```

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Seu problema está no próprio DI que não está inserindo a dependência.

Comment: @MarcosdaCruzSibilioJr. Esqueci de mencionar a mensagem de erro: Call to a member function cadastrarDados() on null , esta função está dentro da model CENTRAL.

Comment: @GabrielHeming , exatamente, criando o objeto manualmente consigo chamar o método, agora através do DI não funcionou.
Gostaria de entender para evitar possíveis erros futuros neste projeto.

Comment: @HelderFerrari provavelmente a sua model não tem o método `$this->central->cadastrarDados`, poste a sua `model` ou `repositório` para podermos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: @William a model tem sim o método cadastrarDados().
Debugando o código, percebi que a falha está no construtor, pois ele não me traz o objeto, desta forma não consigo fazer a chamada para a model.